# Does chatgpt-3.5-turbo API recounts the tokens in billing when sending the conversation history in api

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

When creating a chat app using chatgpt-3.5-turbo model. Does the API consider the whole tokens (including the assistant messages and old set of messages) in billing or just the last message from the user is counted in billing whenever I resend the API request with a new message appended to the conversation?

For eg:

```
messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a kind helpful assistant."},
]
     

while True:
    message = input("User : ")
    if message:
        messages.append(
            {"role": "user", "content": message},
        )
        chat = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=messages
        )
    
    reply = chat.choices[0].message.content
    print(f"ChatGPT: {reply}")
    messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": reply})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [OpenAI document](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/introduction):

> The total number of tokens in an API call affects how much your API call costs, as you pay per token 
> Both input and output tokens count toward these quantities. For example, if your API call used 10 tokens in the message input and you received 20 tokens in the message output, you would be billed for 30 tokens.

To see how many tokens are used by an API call, check the usage field in the API response

```
response['usage']['total_tokens']
```

Each time you `append` previous chats to `messages`, the number of `total_token` will increases. So all tokens of previous messages will be considered in the bill.